# Using placeholders in Annotations on Spring Java Configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-java-config

I'm a little bit lost in Spring's Property Replacement mechanism. Lets say I have this Java Config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class)
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:/config/default.properties")
})
public class ApplicationConfig {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    return pspc;
}
```

Now I want to add a Spring-Data Annotation `@EnableMongoRepositories` and define a custom basepackage for scanning, using a custom placeholder like follows 
`@EnableMongoRepositories("${my.custom.repobasepackage}")`. The Placeholder is defined in my default.properties.

However, this property cannot be resolved here. When diving deeper into Spring's property replacement, I can see that it tries to resolve the property, so it is possible to do so.

However, the underlying `Environment` class which is used to replace the placeholder does not know about my PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, but only know about my SystemProperties and my VM-Props. :-(

I can see that in org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner#getOrCreateEnvironment.java#339 (**I'm using Spring 4.0.1**) my "PropertyPlaceholder" is already in place, so its not a question of ordering in initialization, but is not used, because the used BeanDefinitionRegistry does not implement the Interface `EnvironmentCapable`. Here, my understanding of the Spring App-Context Bootstrapping is at the end.

Can anybody help me out here? Is there a BeanDefinitionRegistry out there which is capable of providing the `Environment` Instance which uses my Property Placeholder?

Any help is highly appreciated!! I got cookies for you! :-))

Cheers, Stefan

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that the `@PropertySources` (you only have one by the way so you don't need the wrapper) are added to the `Environment` *after* the config classes are processed, so it will be too late to resolve on one of the annotations of those classes themselves. You can verify this by setting `my.custom.repobasepackage` as a System property.

As an alternative I encourage you to try out Spring Boot (where `application.properties` is added to the `Environment` before any configuration is processed).